# User input in doubly linked

Tags: c, clang

I am trying to build a program that takes in user input and then reverses the input. The output displays both the original and reverses string. The program compiles but gives me the following error "0ÿÿÿ; Original Linked list Segmentation Fault (core dumped)"

Here is my code:

```
 struct node
 {
 int info;
 struct node *next;
 struct node *prev;
 }node;
 void reverse(struct node **head_1)
 {
 struct node *temp = NULL;
 struct node *current = *head_1;
 while (current !=  NULL)
  {
       temp = current->prev;
       current->prev = current->next;
       current->next = temp;
       current = current->prev;
     }     
      if(temp != NULL )
       *head_1 = temp->prev;
   }    
void push(struct node** head_1, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node =
    (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

     new_node->info  = new_data;
     new_node->prev = NULL;
    new_node->next = (*head_1);   
    if((*head_1) !=  NULL)
      (*head_1)->prev = new_node ;   
      (*head_1)    = new_node;
 }
void printList(struct node *node)
{
while(node!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%s ", node->info);
    node = node->next;
    }
        }

 int main()
 {
struct node* head = NULL;
char str[300], ch;
int i;
printf("enter ");
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n');
{
str[i++]=ch;
str[i]='0';
i=0;
}
    while (str[i]!='\0')
{ 
putchar(str[i++]);
push(&head, ch);
}
    printf("\n Original ");
    printList(head);
    reverse(&head);
    printf("\n Reversed ");
    printList(head);          

     getchar();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using uninitialized variable `i` to access `str`

```
int i;//Unitialized variable
printf("enter ");
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n');
{
str[i++]=ch;//This will acess memory at address str+random value from i
```

Change `int i;` `to int i = 0;`

Also `printf("%s ", node->info);` is incorrect since `node->info` is integer, not string. Should be something like `printf("%d ", node->info);`

There is additional issues I've spot, thru I doubt it is final.

```
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n');//why ;? this will lead to all chars to be skipped and only \n will be passed to the loop body
{
str[i++]=ch;
str[i]='0';//it should be '\0' instead of '0', and there is no sense to set it on each iteration
i=0;//This will reset i on each iteration overwriting previous char
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. I made the changes you mentioned. I am not getting the same error message anymore but now I am getting 
0ÿÿÿ;
 Original 101010101010
 Reversed 101010101010^
with any input